# For loop issue in JQuery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, loops, jsonp

My problem is that its not fetching all page data in loop like if I run the script for a single loop of 1 time then its giving all 20 records but if we increase the loop like let say for 5 time then for all it must give 100 records but it gives random record like 50-55 results and if I run separately one by one in loop then its ok, it gives 100 records

```
function top_rated(){
     for(var k=1;k<=1000;k++){
        var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/', 
        mode = 'movie/top_rated', 
        key = '?api_key=<xxxxxxxxxxxxxx>&page='+k; 
         $.ajax({
            url: url + mode + key, 
            async: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'jsonp', 
            success: function (data) {   
                    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                        if(i == "results") {
                            da = data[i]; 
                            $.each(da, function (j, item) { 
                                if(!item.id) {return false; }
                                fetchmovie(item.id,'top_rated');  
                            });
                        }  
                    });  


            }, 
            error: function (request,error) {
                alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
            }  
        }); 
     }

 }
```

- List item

Comment: The api might have a throttle for the request, which might limit the number of requests that can be sent in a minute or something like that

Comment: it's probably a server side problem.. you're not getting any of that error alert?

Comment: Like @ArunPJohny said, it most likely has to do with a throttle on the API. I know, for example, that rotten tomatoes only lets you do 10k requests (iirc) per day. This website might have something similar in place.

Comment: can't you instead do the loop on server side? like pass `k=1000` to server then do the loop in there? not possible?

Comment: No I am not getting any of that error alert

Comment: you should remove your api key from the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and found this on [their website](http://www.themoviedb.org/talk/5317af69c3a3685c4a0003b1).

> The new system will share the state of an IP address across all 8 instances and provide proper balanced rate limiting. The rate limits themselves remain unchanged (max. 30 requests in a 10 second span). The key difference is in the response handling during your requests and when you trip the rate limits. I'll give you some examples so you can make changes to your code before we go live with this change.

They started enforcing this new limit on March 5, 2014.

Comment: Just don't make more than 30 requests per 10 seconds, or more than 3 requests/sec.

Comment: @user3709703 I would just add a `setInterval()` or something that calls itself every 10 seconds. In the interval, check whether you have made 1k requests yet. If so, clear the interval, otherwise keep on going.